# Is it possible to dynamically pass values to save file as "abc {var1} xyz {var2}.txt" where number of variables could be 1,2,3 or N

Tags: python, python-3.x

Thisis just a python question so people who are not familiar with please just ignore the `Keras` part. I have written a `CustomCallback` in `Keras` where I want so save the model weights dynamically based on the user defined variables.

So inside a callback, we can access the dictionary where we can get all the variable. A user cn enter the desired variables to include in the filenames. Had it been a simple manual call I would have used something like:

```
var1 = logs['var1']
var2 = logs['var2']
model.save_weights(f"abc {var1} xyz {var2}.txt")
```

but I am using a `self` inside class and I have to access the values through a variable so doing `fself.filepath` is not going to work where `self.filepath = "abc {var1} xyz {var2}.txt"`

What should I do here? I  think `format{}` would do but how can I put the values? My users can chose to pass a filename, no name at all and file name with any number of variables.

Comment: Why not pass a list? Then write a function that will loop over the list and append to the file.

Comment: @G.Anderson absolutely not. I am talking of `string` formatting not creating variables variables. Come on man!